# Consistent build type in CMake and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, buildconfig

Is it possible to pass the build type `(Debug, Release)` from Visual Studio to CMake? Currently I am doing this manually in a two step process:

1. Change the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the top project directory as:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1.0)
   set (MyConfig Release)
   set (PROJECT myProject)
   ...
   ```
2. From the Visual Studion pull down menu, I select `Release` version of the build. And then do the build.

I am trying to avoid the mistake of choosing conflicting build types in VS and CMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't change the build type by setting the variable `PROJECT` to "Release". That would be done with the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`.

The `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable should not be used within your CMakeLists.txt, but you pass it to the CMake call. It is passed on command line via `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..`. That's only relevant for build systems, that support a single build type.
For build systems, like the one from Visual Studio, you don't need it all. Multiple configurations are created and you select the build type in your IDE (pull down in VS).

Further reading: https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Compilers_and_Tools

Comment: May be I am not clear on the question: how can I figure out in `CMakeLists.txt` programmatically that I have chosen `Debug` configuration from VS IDE. Perhaps it's not possible at all?

Comment: It is not possible. CMake will generate targets for all build types and you just select which you want to run.